# Android json post to PHP page

Tags: php, android, json

Hi I am trying to post json data to a PHP page by bellow code

```
URL obj = new URL(REST_URL);//(REST_URL + "?d_id=5&ds_remarks=" + et_text);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj
                            .openConnection();
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-type",
                            "application/json");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    con.setDoInput(true);
                    con.setDoOutput(true);

                    String body = "{";
                    body+="d_id:2,ds_remarks:" + et_text;
                    System.out.println(et_text);
                    body+="}";

                    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                            con.getOutputStream());
                    wr.writeBytes(body);
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    responseString = response.toString();
                    Log.d("GetCourse",
                            "Response Code: " + con.getResponseCode());
                    Log.d("Tag", "Response Stream : " + responseString);

                   con.disconnect();

                    System.out.println("=============================================");

                    return responseString;
```

I am getting response to PHP page, but not getting the parameter d_id or ds_remarks on PHP page. I am trying to fetch the parameter by using this code

```
$d_id   = urldecode($_REQUEST['d_id']);
$ds_remarks   = urldecode($_REQUEST['ds_remarks']);
```

Help me someone to fetch the parameter on PHP page.

Thanks

Comment: The JSON should look like this: {"d_id":2,"ds_remarks":"et_text"}. You forgot all the "-signs.

Comment: Thanks Philipp E, I have tried with this format also

Answer (score 3):

It seems you didnt added ur params in httppost like below :

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("d_id", "example"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ds_remarks", "example"));  
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

opening just a connection will not post your parameters .

**Edit** :

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("d_id", "example"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ds_remarks", "example"));
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
wr.write(formatQuery(params));
wr.flush();
wr.close();
os.close();
conn.connect();

private String formatQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    // append the params
    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thansk N5, but httppost and NameValuePair is deprecated on latest version of API 22

Comment: cannot resolve method getQuery error showing :(    Almost achieve, Please help N5

Comment: sorry added partial code plz checkout edited formatQuery API

Comment: No luck yet :( ... Cant find formatQuery also, should I edit this line con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); as I am not sending json data now

Comment: Yes N5, I have added this method also, I can see the parameter string like "d_id=example&ds_remarks=example", but not getting it on PHP page with $_REQUEST['d_id]

Comment: ohh r u using '' single quote or diuble quote? in $_REQUEST??

Comment: Tried single and double both

Comment: both means? is that valid syntax? can u plz change it to $__REQUEST["d_id"] double quotes only???

Comment: Yes I tried to get with $_REQUEST["d_id"], but not getting the value yet

Comment: ohh it seems strange ? any success till now?

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO data SET data_key='".$_REQUEST["d_id"]."', data_value='".$_REQUEST["ds_remarks"]."'");       this is the main query I need to insert to database

Comment: did u printed the variable first? r u sure the variable isnt appering there ? can u plz do `echo $_REQUEST["d_id"];`

Comment: Hi, I echo $_REQUEST["d_id"]; but blank value I am getting :(

Comment: sorry i could catch u up i forgot , i wannted to say that try get request from url in broswer i think issue with php code . try this : url?param1=ur_value&param2=value2